# How to check thread is sleeping in x second c#

Tags: c#

I write application need check if time to `checkLogin()` sleep over > 30 seconds.

Then, it will break this `while loop` and continues the program.

My code like this:

```
while(!Account.checkLogin())
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

How to check like:

```
while(!Account.checkLogin())
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if(Thread.Sleep like 30000)
        continues;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly, you could sum up the iterations and and use them in the termination condition as follows.

```
int MAX_ITERATIONS = 30;
int NumOfIterations = 0;

while(!Account.checkLogin() && NumOfIterations < MAX_ITERATIONS)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    NumOfIterations++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just sleep for 30 seconds:

```
Thread.Sleep(30000);
```

However that's holding up the thread and stops you doing anything inbetween. I prefer to use a `TimeSpan`, for example:

```
DateTime started = DateTime.UtcNow;

while (!Account.checkLogin())
{
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - started;

    if (ts.TotalSeconds >= 30)
        break;

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```